# Apache Kafka Producer inside php-fpm - too many producers connections

Tags: php, kafka-producer-api

**The use case:**
8 servers of 300 php-fpm concurrent child process each, produces records to Apache Kafka.
Each one produces 1 Kafka record, 1000 records per second.

**Why do we need so many connections?**
We have a web API, that is getting 60K calls per minute. Those requests are doing many things and processed via thousands of web php-fpm workers (unfortunately). As part of the request handling, we produce events to Kafka.

**The problem:**
I cannot find a way to persist connections between php-fpm web requests, creating some that seems to me so inefficient as might hit Kafka bounderies(will it?).

The result is 1000 producer connections per second getting established, sending one single record ach and getting closed just after.

I read here https://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/648zrk/kafka_php_71_library/ that php-rdkafka is efficient, but I dont know if it can solve this issue.

I thought that Opcache might be handy to reuse connections but I cannot find a way to do it.

**The question**
Is establishing and closing 1000 connections per second fast and cheap or is a proxy with cheap connectivity that will reuse Kafka connection a must for such a use case?

Comment: Keep in mind that you are asking too many questions and they are too broad or opinion-based. Please check the [help/on-topic] and the help page [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.

Comment: @Progman thank and I hope that I managed to make it concise and specific this time.

Comment: Why are you sending 1000 messages each individually with one connection each instead of sending all of them over one connection? You will save 999 connections if you use only one for sending 1000 messages.

Comment: This is the issue, I am getting API 60K API per minute, done via thousands of web workers. Those API calls doing lots of things and returning response. In addition the shall send a message for later batch processing to a Message Queue, namely Kafka. I updated the description of the question.

Comment: You should run a stress test/performance test to actually get data of your performance. Otherwise it's just guessing how to improve the performance if you don't know if and where something isn't fast enough.

Comment: I am aware that this is an old topic. However, IMO the only correct way to solve this is to add a local queue (e.g. redis or beanstalk) on your servers. Then create a worker (per server) which processes these records in batch and which sends them to kafka. This also improves High Availability. If you cannot reach kafka for a short moment, your data still resides in your local queue so you do not miss anything.